# How to arsort the following array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [angular] => 2
)
Array
(
    [android sdk] => 3
)
Array
(
    [application] => 1
)
```

Here is the code to arsort the array above:

```
$weight = array($weight);
$dev = array_combine($missing, $weight);
arsort($dev);

foreach($dev as $x => $x_value) 
   echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>";
```

Output:

> Key=angular, Value=2 Key=android sdk, Value=3 Key=application, Value=1

But I'd like the result to be in descending order, like below:

> Key=android sdk, Value=3 Key=angular, Value=2 Key=application, Value=1

Comment: "Here is my array"  _Which_ array is that?  You have multiple variables in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. $dev is Array
(
    [angular] => 2
)
Array
(
    [android sdk] => 3
)
Array
(
    [application] => 1
)

Comment: If that's what `$dev` is, then you are _not_ getting the output that you posted above using the code that you provide.  That code would trigger Notices.

Answer (score 0):

What you want might be [an usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function, where you can provide your own comparison logic.

```
$weight = array($weight);
$dev = array_combine($missing, $weight);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}


usort($dev, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work with my array $dev. It breaks my page.

Comment: it's a "pseudocode", you should adjust it to your needs